# Can you "Queue" webRequest to the background to speed up your program?

Tags: c#, html, webrequest, performance

The slowest part of my code are these lines right here:

```
        string responseString;
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return responseString;
```

is there a way to "queue up" multiple webRequest and have them download in the background while my code parses the HTML between page requests? Is there a name/method for this I can google? any links or code are much appreciated! thanks!

*edit: full getHTML() code added

Comment: The title doesn't need C#, that is where tags are for.

Comment: You can go [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the async methods, to unblock your UI and handle the requests there.

But your posted line of code should do almost nothing.
The request to the server occurs when calling the Response.
With:

```
var respone = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Just use the, to unblock the UI and handle it after the async progresss ist done.

```
var response = webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
// or BeginResponse() ... EndResponse();
```

You can read the following for further information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Feel free to extend my answer to your hearts delight.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a producer consumer style of programming.  Whenever you see that the `BlockingCollection` is often a good tool.  It's a collection (by default using a queue) that is designed to be accessed from multiple threads safely.

You can start out with your consumers that are asynchronously making the requests and then putting the results of the request into the queue:

```
BlockingCollection<string> queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

foreach(string url in links)
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync()
        .ContinueWith(t => new StreamReader(t.Result).ReadToEnd());
```

Then you can have code that processes each of the results in the queue as they come in:  (There can easily be more than one consumer if that makes sense as well.)

```
foreach(var fileText in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    processText(fileText);
}
```